# $_POST not working on certain web hosting

Tags: codeigniter, iis, post

Recently, we've moved from one web host to another. The PHP version of our web hosting now is *5.3.13* and the older webhosting is *5.3.5* and on my localhost PHP version *5.4.7*.

I've adjusted some jQuery code like `$.post()` to `$.ajax()` but that didn't help at all. It's working fine our old web hosting and on my localhost, what puzzled me is why it's not working on our new web hosting. Is this something to do with IIS?

Comment: the server returns a 404 error?

Comment: Hi @AndreiZhamoida thanks for the quick response. No it doesn't. It's actually returning 200 but the thing is it returns the validation error message because the $_POST was not capture/posted on the next step/procedure.

Comment: Hi @AndreiZhamoida actually the whole website that has <form> tags has a problem anyway here's a snippet of my code using $.ajax

Comment: sorry here you go. $.ajax({
  
  url:'/controller/function_name',
  type:'POST',
  data:data,
  dataType:'json',
  success:function(result){
   if ( result.success === 1){
   flashMessage(result.message);
   loadCartSummary(); // function
   loadCartContent();// another function
   }else{
    flashMessage(result.message);
   }
  }
 });

Answer (score 0):

Well, that if you put empty data object or string to be sent to the server?
Try to use `console.log(data)` before sending ajax request. Мake sure what `data` is key/value pairs. `{product_id: "3452", variant_id: "2"}`

After make easy `var_dump($_POST)` in the beginning of your `/controller/function_name`. I think here is problem. If it will empty debug your app to find out where $_POST lost.

Comment: Hi @andrei I've tried to edit my code to this 
$.ajax({
  
  url:'/cart/add_to_cart_multiple_addons',
  type:'POST',
  data:data_,
  dataType:'json',
  success:function(result){
   console.log(result);
   if ( result.success === 1){
   flashMessage(result.message);
   loadCartSummary();
   loadCartContent();
   }else{
    flashMessage(result.message);
   }
  }
 });
but it doesn't display anything.

Comment: open firebug or chrome console and make sure what your $_POST is not empty. `success:function(result){ console.log(result);` - `console.log()` in this case shows **request from server**. Put it before `$.ajax()`

Comment: Hi sorry for a late reply.. The issue is on server side.. the new hosting don't have apache. Thanks for all the help.